# vnc screen is freezed, not fixed by rebooting

Tags: vnc, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I had several programs running on a server, which I connect to with VNC Viewer. And for some reason firefox became unresponsive, and the screen froze. I followed these steps:

1. `vncserver kill -9 :1` to kill the process
2. `vncserver :1` to start a new one
3. `sudo reboot`

However, when I reconnected, the screen was still frozen and I could not even move the mouse cursor. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops! I found the reason for that, I had mistakenly checked the view-only checkbox. Here is the screenshot:

[image]